# Apex performance issue - Happening in the first time in 6 AM to 9 AM in EST

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, sales

I am attaching debug log which is showing CPU is all most hit limit.

> Number of SOQL queries: 2 out of 100
>     Number of query rows: 5619 out of 50000
>     Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
>     Number of DML statements: 3 out of 150
>     Number of DML rows: 47 out of 10000
>     Maximum CPU time: 9433 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
>     Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000

here is main parts of debug log

> 35.0   APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
>   07:39:13.0 (67000)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00516000006pG2P|srekal01@roberthalf.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-07:00
>   07:39:13.0 (96969)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   07:39:13.0 (101392)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|06616000002epo1|VF: /apex/CreatingAndMaintaingQuestions
>   07:39:13.0 (23821501)|METHOD_ENTRY|[8]|01p16000004wQcq|CreatingAndMaintaingQuestionsCtrl.CreatingAndMaintaingQuestionsCtrl()
>   07:39:13.0 (23888624)|METHOD_EXIT|[8]|CreatingAndMaintaingQuestionsCtrl
>   07:39:13.0 (53865203)|DML_BEGIN|[317]|Op:Update|Type:Requisition__c|Rows:1
>   07:39:13.0 (78045441)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Validation:Requisition:a0P1600000BwPBy
>   07:39:13.0 (79220306)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Validation:Requisition:a0P1600000BwPBy
>   07:39:13.0 (109513715)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q16000001MACT|RequisitionTrigger on Requisition trigger event AfterUpdate for [a0P1600000BwPBy]
>   07:39:13.0 (153755280)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|RequisitionTrigger on Requisition trigger event AfterUpdate for [a0P1600000BwPBy]
>   07:39:13.0 (154314997)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:01I16000002cLv0
>   07:39:13.0 (176993997)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L16000000GqND
>   07:39:13.177 (177081284)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00DA0000000KKvp|30016000000TzHJ|301160000000NCC
>   07:39:13.177 (178903917)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|2674330c60d0fd141f9753e2ecfa15c4531840e-73d0|Update Candidate Status When Requisition Status Changes
>   07:39:13.179 (179273741)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
>   07:39:13.179 (180204151)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|2674330c60d0fd141f9753e2ecfa15c4531840e-73d0|Update Candidate Status When Requisition Status Changes
>   07:39:13.179 (182823203)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|2674330c60d0fd141f9753e2ecfa15c4531840e-73d0|Update Candidate Status When Requisition Status Changes
>   07:39:13.179 (182835114)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1
>   07:39:13.0 (184834647)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09L16000000GqND
>   07:39:13.0 (203082844)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:01I16000002cLv0
>   07:39:13.0 (204337281)|DML_END|[317]
>   07:39:13.0 (204551394)|DML_BEGIN|[321]|Op:Upsert|Type:Question__c|Rows:32
>   07:39:13.0 (623423795)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q16000001MACS|QuestionTrigger on Question trigger event AfterInsert for [a0O1600000NBNSd, a0O1600000NBNSe, a0O1600000NBNSf, a0O1600000NBNSg, a0O1600000NBNSh, a0O1600000NBNSi, a0O1600000NBNSj, a0O1600000NBNSk, a0O1600000NBNSl, a0O1600000NBNSm, a0O1600000NBNSn, a0O1600000NBNSo, a0O1600000NBNSp, a0O1600000NBNSq, a0O1600000NBNSr, a0O1600000NBNSs, a0O1600000NBNSt, a0O1600000NBNSu, a0O1600000NBNSv, a0O1600000NBNSw, a0O1600000NBNSx, a0O1600000NBNSy, a0O1600000NBNSz, a0O1600000NBNT0, a0O1600000NBNT1, a0O1600000NBNT2, a0O1600000NBNT3, a0O1600000NBNT4, a0O1600000NBNT5, a0O1600000NBNT6, a0O1600000NBNT7, a0O1600000NBNT8]
>   07:39:13.0 (626408500)|METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|01p16000004wQcz|QuestionTriggerHandler.QuestionTriggerHandler()
>   07:39:13.0 (626428661)|METHOD_EXIT|[7]|QuestionTriggerHandler
>   07:39:13.0 (626458396)|METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|01p16000004wQcz|QuestionTriggerHandler.afterInsert(List)
>   07:39:13.0 (626535199)|METHOD_ENTRY|[10]|01p16000004wQcz|QuestionTriggerHandler.updateAccountQuestionMasterList(List)
>   07:39:13.0 (630356391)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[24]|Aggregations:2|SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Company_Questions__r), (SELECT Id FROM Requisitions__r WHERE (Open_For_Submission__c = TRUE AND Form_Created__c = TRUE)) FROM Account
>   07:39:13.0 (908437159)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[24]|Rows:479
>   07:39:16.812 (3918001865)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[48]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id FROM Requisition__c
>   07:39:16.812 (4186422097)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[48]|Rows:5140
>   07:39:49.835 (37373727559)|METHOD_ENTRY|[48]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
>   07:39:49.835 (37373788041)|METHOD_EXIT|[48]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
>   *** Skipped 156024742 bytes of detailed log
>   07:39:49.835 (37377209166)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[49]|ques|{"LastModifiedDate":"2017-05-26T14:39:14.000Z","Question_Text__c":"Location worked","IsDeleted":false,"Display_Dependant_Va (6 more) ...":"Yes","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD","Name":"Q-1035396","SystemModstamp":"2017-05-26T14:39:14.000Z","OwnerId":"00516000006pG2PAAU","CreatedById":"00516000006pG2PAAU","Requisition__c":"a0P1600000BwPByEAN","Type__c":"Multi-line text","Template_Question__c":"a0O1600000p2sPZEAY","RecordTypeId":"012160000014KvOAAU","CreatedDate":"2017-05-26T14:39:14.000Z","Order__c":20,"Id":"a0O1600000NBNSwEAP","LastModifiedById":"00516000006pG2PAAU"}|0x3532e45f
>   07:39:49.835 (37377217673)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[49]
>   07:39:49.835 (37377240830)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[50]

I am thinking following SOQL query is taking longer time..

```
for(Question__c quest :[SELECT 
                            id, Question_Text__c, Picklist_Options__c , Type__c, Order__c, recordTypeId,
                            recordType.name, Display_Dependant_Value__c, Display_Dependant_Question__c
                        FROM 
                            Question__c 
                        WHERE 
                            Template_Question__c = null
                            AND(
                                (recordType.name =: System.Label.Record_Type_Standard_Template)
                                OR(Id IN :compQuesSet AND recordType.name = :System.Label.Record_Type_Custom_Template)
                                OR (recordType.name = :System.Label.Record_type_Form_Question 
                                    AND Requisition__c =: requisition.Id
                                )
                            )
                        ORDER BY 
                            Order__c]){
    //...
}
```

it is causing timeout many times.
Could you suggest how to solve problem?

Comment: SOQL doesn't even count against your CPU usage.

Comment: The query itself may take a while to run, but I believe that SOQL itself doesn't count towards the CPU limit (take a look at the `5 CPU time is calculated for all executions` aside about a quarter down [the page documenting goverrnor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) . It's much more likely that your issue resides inside the `for` loop that you've provided. Using the analysis perspective in the dev console (open a log, Debug -> Switch Perspective -> Analysis (predefined) ) should help narrow your search.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your query I noticed that you are querying on NULL.

In Salesforce a query on NULL requires a full table scan unless you add a custom index to it ([See Best Practises](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/02/force-com-soql-best-practices-nulls-and-formula-fields.html)). I would be careful with this query and put the Template_Question__c = null part at the end of the query if this is needed and also add an index.

Depending on how big your Question__c object is (e.g. the number of records it contains) this query can take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Derek, Adrian for response.

I filed two tickets with sales force and they did not help.

Finally i did following things.

I wrote scheduled job in sales force to run for every 15 minutes between 3 AM to 6 AM ( PST ) or 6 AM to 9 AM (EST). This scheduled  job just run above query. This query started filling database cache before user started using the same query. So it is now working. Now user not getting timeout values. surprising news is I did not tune the query.

I am posting this solution because it may help others for problem.

This site helped me to find right solution. Thanks to all.